# Average Time Duration in PowerBI Matrix

Tags: datetime, time, powerbi, format, dax

Is anyone aware of a way in which one can calculate an average time duration in hh:mm:ss format in a matrix visual in PowerBI?

In my table, I have these Date/Time Opened and Date/Time Closed fields.

[image]

I created a new column called Time to Close by subtracting Date/Time Closed from Date/Time Opened.

[image]

I am at a complete loss as to how I can depict an average of these time durations in the HH:mm:ss format by adding the Time to Close field as a value on a matrix visual because it's only presenting the data in a hierarchical manner.

[image]

I've tried converting to the number of seconds and running an average on that, but again it still only shows average seconds, not the HH:mm:ss format that I need.

Has anyone had issues with this before? I can get everything exactly how I need it in my table, but not in the Matrix visual. I've tried a number of DAX measures, and I'm still striking out.

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mik's answer is almost there, but the string formatting rules of Power BI's `FORMAT()` function are slightly different: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax

The below should work, where `varAvrSeconds` is your measure (or variable) producing the correct answer in seconds:

```
FORMAT(
      TIME ( 0, 0, varAvrSeconds)
      ,"hh:nn:ss"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this solves the case?

```
FORMAT(
      TIME ( 0, 0, varAvrSeconds)
      ,"HH:MM:SS"
)
```